# When is_primary flag set to non-zero value in android contacts?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

Hi all
Currently i am geting `is_primary` value 1 oly for the contacts which have more than 1 contact. numbers.
e.g. **Contac Z** having phone numbers
1. **+1-33445566**
2. **+1-99882233**
**3. +1-33221122**
I have few questions about the Contacts in android
1. When the `is_primary` is set to non-zero value?
2. Why it is not set to non-zero for the contacts which dont have multiple phone numbers ?
e.g. **Contact A** having contact number lets say **+1-22334455**.
I gone through all the resources available but not got satisfyinh answer.
Please help
Thank you 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`IS_PRIMARY` can be set by a `SyncAdapter` to signal to the system this value has a higher value/priority over other items of the same type (e.g. the main email of the contact compared to the other email addresses on record for that contact).

It can also be set by the user, via the Contacts app, each contacts app behaves a bit differently, but in most case you can long press on a phone number to get a menu pop, in which you can mark the selected phone number as the default (same goes for emails).
Note that you can perform that action even if that contact has only one phone number.

In general it's up to any app that has `WRITE_CONTACTS` permission to mark a certain data item as `IS_PRIMARY`, either to sync some primary-state from the cloud, to follow a user manual action like setting a phone as the default, or any other use-case an app might have